# How to add password to existing PDF file

Tags: vba, excel, adobe

Goal: Using Excel VBA, add a password to an existing PDFfile.

I’ve got AdobePDFMakerX. I can’t figure out how to add a password to an existing PDF file using Excel VBA. How can I do this?